# Python - Write a string in every new line

Tags: python, file, text

I'm having a problem with how can I write a string in every new line in a text file. Please see attached image:

[image]

Above image is the original text file. Now I want to add some text in every newline. Please see attached image:

[image]

Now I added the word "END". How can I do it in python? I tried to use the normal file reading then adding this stuff:

```
if 'PING' in line:
    new_file.write("END")
elif 'ST' in line:
    new_file.write("END")
etc. .
```

But I think this way isn't flexible. Do you guys have any ideas on how can I do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: @Selcuk it's just a bytes size.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, what is the total size of the file? If it is small, you can read whole file into memory (instead of reading it line by line) and then replace the strings `"\n\n"` with `"\nEND\n"`.

Comment: @Selcuk it is just a small file sir, how can I do it sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make several mistakes:

1. A newline is not the same as an empty line. You look to replace empty lines with your text.
2. `PING` has nothing to do with an empty line.

To achieve what I mentioned in point 1, you can use the following snippet

```
with open('myfile','rw') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.isspace():
            file.write("your text")
        else:
            file.write(line)
```